# Query parameters binding into DTO, how to ignore specific param?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is there any good way to ignore some request query parameters from binding to DTO parameters?

```
@Data // setters and getters  
class Dto {
  private String param1;
  private String param2;
}
```

```
@GetMapping("/hello-world") 
@ResponseBody 
public ResponseEntity<Dto> sayHello(Dto params) 
{ ... }
```

I would like to exclude binding of specific param in such case.

After some research I can't find any solution for it, any help?

Comment: by excluding from binding do you mean that you'd like the params to be considered as optional or what exactly?

Comment: I would like that this param in DTO will be not set, even if request will have it.

Comment: I think you should take a look at JsonProperty.Access https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html, if you mark a field as @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY) it will only be visible on the response, and will be ignored at write team (when sending the request)